# Change the language of Facebook Connect button

Tags: facebook

How can I change the Facebook Connect button's language and is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, you should note that according to [Facebook's official docs, If you're rendering a social plugin in an IFrame, Facebook automatically translates the text because it's based on the viewing user's locale.](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization)

If however, you still want to do this, you can try and [render some XFBML with Internationalization tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization#markup).